# Why can't you use dot product on vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces, inner-products

I'm taking college Linear Algebra and Calculus right now. I'm a bit confused because in Calculus we're continuing to use the dot product just as in high school but in Lin Alg the prof said that you can't use the dot product or multiply two vectors. I understand it has something to do with closure (it needs to be a function from R_N to R_N). What's the exact reason and why am I doing different things in 2 math classes ?

Comment: It's probably because later it will be introduced in a more general form in the linear algebra course.

Comment: This sounds like an issue where something has been lost in translation between you and your professor. If you have two vectors $\mathbb{R}^n$, say, then there is a dot product between them and the result is a real number. This is not a vector in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (which I only mention because you included the word *closure* in your  question). So you should not, for example, think of the dot product as a typical product, since if you had three vectors $x, y, z$, then you could not compute the dot product $x \cdot y \cdot z$.

Comment: This is vague. I can think of at least two possible interpretations; one is the one david suggests, and the other is that you may be working in an abstract vector space $V$, and such a thing is not equipped with a dot product by default (called in this context an inner product).

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Why do abstract vector spaces not allow dot products ?

Comment: vector spaces do not *require* dot products; if one has an inner product, then it's an inner product space

Comment: @anirudh Because it makes it a more general notion, and indeed some vector spaces occuring in practice (e.g. whose elements are polynomials) don't have (a natural) dot product.